# ngrok Spawn unknown error node.js when running a server script

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, server, node-modules

I have been trying to run a server script in node.js, and I have been getting this error.
[image]

Here's the piece of code which is showing the error:
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happened for me because I was on the new macOS "Apple Silicon" in the terminal Apple will not prompt you to install Rosetta which is required for certain apps to run. Simply running `softwareupdate --install-rosetta` solved the issue for me.

More information about Rosetta here https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT211861